# Problems with user login in the system

Tags: django, django-views

i have created two custom forms based on UserCreationForm and AuthenticationForm. After registering a user, I want to log him in immediately, and I succeeded. But when I just want to log in, the error {'invalid_login': 'Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.', 'inactive': 'This account is inactive.'} even if all the entered data is correct.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='accounts/images', default='default/user.jpg', blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=130, null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.username}, {self.email}"
```

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
        
    labels = {
        'username': "Username",
        'password': 'Password'
    }
```

views.py

```
class RegisterView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = RegisterForm()
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
            user.set_password(raw_password)
            user.save()
            
            # Додайте логування для перевірки, чи користувач збережений
            # print(f"User {username} saved successfully.")
            
            authenticated_user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            if authenticated_user is not None:
                login(request, authenticated_user)
                return redirect('blog:index')
            
        print(f"Form errors: {form.errors}")
        return render(request, "accounts/register.html", {'form': form})


class LoginView(View):
    
    def get(self, request):
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                print(f"User {username} login successfully.")
                return redirect('blog:index')
            
        print(f"Form errors: {form.error_messages}")
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})
```

template login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Login user
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Log in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

register form

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
profile_image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
address = forms.CharField(max_length=130, required=False)
date_of_birth = forms.DateField(required=False)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',
              'profile_image', 'address', 'date_of_birth']

labels = {
    'username': "Ім'я користувача",
    'email': 'Електронна пошта',
    'password1': 'Пароль',
    'password2': 'Підтвердження пароля',
    'profile_image': 'Ваше фото',
    'address': 'Адреса проживання',
    'date_of_birth': 'Дата народження'
}
```

Comment: share your user creation form code too

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `is_active` attribute of your user. Since you are **not** using the super convenient [`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) function provided by django your code fails to set `<youruser>.is_active = True`.

The default ModelBackend does not allow those users to log in. Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active).

Try this:

```py
class RegisterView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
            user = create_user(
                username=username,
                password=password,
                yourfield1=yourdata1,
                yourfield2=yourdata2,
            )
            # user.save() not needed anymore

        # [...]
```

Of course you could also simply add a line like `user.is_active = True` to your code and it should work equally well.

Comment: I have already solved this issue by adding an additional request parameter to:
form = LoginForm(request, request.POST)
in method post. The authorization has indeed started working, but how does it work?

Comment: i think it might be because of the custom authorization form.

Answer (score 0):

```
class LoginView(View):

def get(self, request):
    form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = LoginForm(request, request.POST) # added request here
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('blog:index')
        
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})
```